# os.listdir and os.path.isdir confusion, isdir is acting random?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this simple process below for listing the contents of a folder:

```
def some_process(self):


    dir3 = os.listdir('/Users/somepath/programming/somepathanother/Data_samples')
    for d in dir3:
        if os.path.isdir(d):
            print "DIR: " + d
        elif os.path.isfile(d):
            print "FILE: " + d


    print "PATH THREE:"
    print str(dir3)

    sys.exit(0)
```

The actual contents of the Data_samples folder is:
dir1
dir2
dir3
dir4
file.zip
anotherfile.zip
dir5

The output of the process does not work as expected. For a file it just prints:

`FILE .DS_Store` 
and nothing else (should print out file.zip and anotherfile.zip)

I also realize that if I copy the resourcetest.py file and it's corresponding ini file into this folder and run it then it does see it

```
FILE: .DS_Store
FILE: resourcetest.ini
FILE: resourcetest.py
```

The full output of `print str(dir3)`

```
PATH THREE: 
['.DS_Store', 'dir1', 'dir2', 'dir3', 'dir4', 'resourcetest.ini','resourcetest.py', 'test.file', 'test.zip', 'dir5']
```

Then should also print out dir1 dir2 dir3 dir4 as DIR: " , yet none of this happens and I have no idea why, though in an odd twist if I execute this code from the folder that is listed, it does show everything correctly.

Is this an anomaly of running python 2.7 from the mac os x terminal, or am I missing something else here.  Is my thinking on the usage of listdir and isdir wrong?

Comment: .DS_Store is created by osx... can you give us the output of `print(dir3)`?

Comment: added more code, I am sort of thinking it is a permission issue.   The files I copy in finder, are there.  The ones I built via touch in the terminal, and none of the directories are seen.  Again this changes if i run it from the folder that is specified in the listdir, then it works as expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`listdir` gives only the names, not the full path. You will need to create the full path:

```
for d in dir3:
    path = os.path.join('/Users/somepath/programming/somepathanother/Data_samples', d)
    if os.path.isdir(path):
        ...
```

Comment: Probably a better way would be to use `next(os.walk("/Users/somepath/..."))`. That will give the path, a list of directory names, and a list of file names. That sounds like exactly what is needed.

Comment: @zondo `is.walk` will traverse all the sub directories recursively, which might not be what the OP has in mind.

Comment: @HaiVu: That's why I used `next()`. That will result in only the first set, not traversing the subdirectories.